# select2 Maximum call stack exceeded on dependent dropdown

Tags: jquery, select

i have tow dropdown the first one show the item by number ,and the second one show the item names so the user can select the item  by item number or by item name and if he select item number another dropdown will update selected value her is my code

i create simple on change function to update another dropdown value

```js
$('.select').select2({
  "width":"100px"
});


$(document).on("change", "#block_name", function () {
  id = $(this).val();
  $("#block_number").select2('val',id);
});

$(document).on("change", "#block_number", function () {
  id = $(this).val();
  $("#block_name").select2('val',id);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select name="block" id="block_name" class="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>

</select>

<select name="block_number" id="block_number" class="select">
  <option value="1">block1</option>
  <option value="2">block2</option>
  <option value="3">block3</option>
  <option value="4">block4</option>
  <option value="5">block5</option>
</select>
```

any one could  help me i will appreciate  it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the value of the select2 dropdown triggers the change event, causing an endless loop. So you have to have a case for that. Something like this:

```
$('.select').select2({
   "width":"100px"
});


$(document).on("change", "#block_name", function () {
   id = $(this).val();
   if($("#block_number").val() != id){
      $("#block_number").select2('val',id);
   }
});

$(document).on("change", "#block_number", function () {
   id = $(this).val();
   if($("#block_name").val() != id){
       $("#block_name").select2('val',id);
   }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select').css({width:100});

    $("#block_name").on("change", function () {
        id = $(this).val();
        $("#block_number option[value = " + id + "]").prop("selected",true);
    })

    $("#block_number").on("change", function () {
        id = $(this).val();
        $("#block_name option[value = " + id + "]").prop("selected",true);
    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
</head>
<body>
    <select name="block" id="block_name" class="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>

</select>

<select name="block_number" id="block_number" class="select">
  <option value="1">block1</option>
  <option value="2">block2</option>
  <option value="3">block3</option>
  <option value="4">block4</option>
  <option value="5">block5</option>
</select>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select').css({width:100});
    
    $("#block_name").on("change", function () {
        id = $(this).val();
        $("#block_number option[value = " + id + "]").prop("selected",true);
    })
    
    $("#block_number").on("change", function () {
        id = $(this).val();
        $("#block_name option[value = " + id + "]").prop("selected",true);
    })
})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @maali , check my answer!

Comment: thank you  @ehsan  your code  working  too  but i used the  Eddie solution